# Beginner. Just don't find the error. python export in to CSV

Tags: python, csv

I have to write a script to write the table in a CSV file. Since I'm still a beginner in programming, I just can't find the error. With "#print(rows_data)" the data is displayed in the console. But unfortunately not in the CSV file which is empty. Maybe someone has a tip?

```
url = browser.page_source #html_content = url.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(url, "lxml")


table_aufderseite = []

roh1_table = soup.find(id="TransactionsContent")#"span", attrs={})
# es gibt zwei Tabellen die leider identisch sind und keine unique ID haben. ich brauche die zweite...
for table_list in range(2):
    table_aufderseite = roh1_table.find_all('table')
gdp_table = table_aufderseite[2] # ok richtige Tabelle jetzt, das ist gdp_table.

table_rows = gdp_table.find_all('tr')


for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    rows_data = [tabdata.text.strip().replace("\t", "").replace("\n", "") for tabdata in td]
    
#    print(rows_data)

    with open('bahncardkreditkarten-umsatz.csv', 'w', newline='') as filechen:
        writer = csv.writer(filechen)
        writer.writerows(rows_data)
```

Thank's

Comment: @Triims That's what `writerows()` does.

Answer (score 1):

The argument to `writer.writerows()` should be a 2-dimensional list, but `rows_data` is just one row.

You can collect all the rows into a list of lists. Then after that loop is done, call `writerows()` with everything.

```
all_rows = []
for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    rows_data = [tabdata.text.strip().replace("\t", "").replace("\n", "") for tabdata in td]
    all_rows.append(rows_data)
    

with open('bahncardkreditkarten-umsatz.csv', 'w', newline='') as filechen:
    writer = csv.writer(filechen)
    writer.writerows(all_rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting your rows each time through your loop. Presumably the last row in the table you are reading is empty and thus the file is ending up empty

In this section:

```
for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    rows_data = [tabdata.text.strip().replace("\t", "").replace("\n", "") for tabdata in td]
    
#    print(rows_data)

    with open('bahncardkreditkarten-umsatz.csv', 'w', newline='') as filechen:
        writer = csv.writer(filechen)
        writer.writerows(rows_data)
```

You are looping over each table row, and for each row, you open the .csv file anew and write to it from the beginning. You should instead, open the file once, and loop over the table rows *after* opening it, adding new data each time through your loop, or collect the rows together in a single array and write them out with a single call to writerows.

Alternatively, you could open the file with `'a'` instead of `'w'` to append to the file; however this seems needlessly inefficient and messy.

Answer (score 0):

Hallo Harmar and Jack,

I know that is quick and dirty. I'm not a programmer and I need quickly the skript. If the jobs works I will the script "cleaing".